# How do I repeat a method every 10 minutes after a button press and end it on another button press

Tags: android

I am writing an Android app that retrieves the phone's current location and sends it too a webserver.
I want to be able to press a start button and have the app continue to retrieve and send the location at a predetermined interval (say every 10 minutes) and then have it stop on another button press.

Here is the code for my buttons:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    //When the button is clicked
    public void onClick(View v) {
            finishButton.setEnabled(true);
            startButton.setEnabled(false);

            //Loops every 10mins
            pingCurrentLocation();

        }
    });

  finishButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    //When the button is clicked
    public void onClick(View v) {
            startButton.setEnabled(true);
            finishButton.setEnabled(false);

            pingCurrentLocation();

        }
    });  
}
```

pingCurrentLocation is the function that gets the location and sends it.

I know that using an AlarmManager would probably achieve what I want but I have been unable to make sense of any of it. Are there any clear steps or templates that will work in my situation.

Comment: I don't get it, Alarm manager is an ideal way to do it.... I am doing the exact same thing using alarm manager. Service will eat up memory and I don't particularly like threads so I chose AlarmManager. Do you want me to share my code here ?

Comment: I know it would be ideal its just that im having a lot of problems implementing it. If you wouldn't mind sharing your code that would be great.

Comment: @X-Man - I have updated the answer with details on using an AlarmManager/BroadcaseReceiver combination.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{   

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {   
    //get and send location information
  }
}
```

and add the same to  your `AndroidManifest` so that the Receiver is registered

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.coderplus.AlarmReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
</receiver>
```

Now you can set a repeating alarm from your `Activity` which will invoke the receiver every 10 minutes:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),600000,
                                                                      pendingIntent);
```

and to cancel the alarm, call `cancel()` on the `AlarmManager` using an equivalent `PendingIntent`

```
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

---

or if you don't want to use `AlarmManager` / `BroadcastReceiver`, then something like this will help you out. Before you go for it, check - [difference between timer and alarmmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579034/difference-between-timer-and-alarmmanager)

```
private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {           
      //get and send location information 
    }
}
```

initialize the `Timer` and `Timer` task:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
MyTimerTask myTimerTask= new MyTimerTask();
```

Stopping or starting the `Timer`

```
//to Stop
myTimer.cancel();
//to start
myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 600000); //(timertask,delay,period)
```

Refer 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: This works however there is a problem. When I press the start button which performs `myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 600000);` and press the stop/cancel button it and then press start again the apps crashes.

Comment: @coderplus: What if I kill the application from memory? Will it still work?

Comment: how you unregister the receiver here?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Android-TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) or [Android-AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for sending location data to every 10 minutes. Look at this SO question [Track Gps At every 10 minutes using timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921916/track-gps-at-every-10-minutes-using-timer-in-android)  also this one [Good way of getting the user's location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android)

**TimerTask:**

The `TimerTask` class represents a task to run at a specified time. The task may be run once or repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did.

created an alarm manager object first, and set the repeating timer

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = alarmMgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmIntent = alarmIntent = new Intent("AlarmIntentReceiver"); 
PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 30*1000, 3*60*1000,  pendingAlarmIntent); //start in 30 secs and rest in 3 mins interval
```

Created an activity based on that intent name that will capture the intent and execute it's code in the interval specified, you can also create a broadcast receiver if you like.

To cancel it in your button click event. Write this

```
alarmMgr.cancel(pendingAlarmIntent);
```

Comment: What is the `context` ? What is its values? sorry im new to programming.

Comment: Context is interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc. You can read more here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)... If you don't understand context then you probably need to go through some of android fundamentals first...

Answer (score 0):

You can start a service which will check for user location & send it to your specified web address as mentioned below.

you can get more information about service [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

```
public class TaxiLocationUpdator extends Service{
    Location location;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void  onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        updateNotification();
    }

    //int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startId){
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
            handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second
        Log.v("Location Servics", "Start Service");
    }

     private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                DisplayLoggingInfo();           
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 15000); // 60 seconds here you can give your time
            }
        };    

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("Location Servics", "Destroy Service");
    }

    public boolean isOnline(){
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isconnected;
            if (netInfo==null || !netInfo.isConnected())
            isconnected=false;
            else
            isconnected=true;
            Log.v("isOnliNe",isconnected+"");
            return isconnected;
        }

    protected void updateNotification() {
             LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationlistener();

             lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, normallocationwait, 0.250f, locationListener);
             location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       }

       private class MyLocationlistener implements LocationListener {

         public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
             if(location!=null){
                 if(location.hasAccuracy()){
                       dumpLocation(location);
                 }else{
                       dumpLocation(location);
                }
             } 
         }

         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
             Log.v("Loc Update","\nProvider disabled: " + provider);
         }

         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
             Log.v("Loc Update","\nProvider enabled: " + provider);
         }

         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
             Log.v("Loc Update","\nProvider status changed: " + provider + ", status="
                        + status + ", extras=" + extras);
         }

         private void dumpLocation(Location location) {
                 if (location == null)
                        Log.v("Loc Update","\nLocation[unknown]");
                 else{
                         Log.v("Loc Update","\n" + location.toString());
                         Log.v("Demo", location.toString());
                                 String url  = Your url;
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         if(isOnline()){
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                            try {
                                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                Log.v("Message", response.toString());
                              } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                  Log.e("Sending Message",e.getMessage().toString());
                              } catch (IOException e) {
                                  Log.e("Sending Message",e.getMessage().toString());
                            }
                     }
                } 
          }

         public boolean isOnline(){
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isconnected;
            if (netInfo==null || !netInfo.isConnected())
            isconnected=false;
            else
            isconnected=true;
            Log.v("isOnliNe",isconnected+"");
            return isconnected;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread and a handler

```
   Handler alarmCheckHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

                System.out.println("getting message from alarm thread");
                //Call your function for ping



    };
Thread alarmCheckThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            synchronized (this) {
                while (checkflag) {
                    i++;
                    try {
                        sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (i == 600) {
                        alarmCheckHandler.sendMessage(alarmCheckHandler
                                .obtainMessage());
                        i = 0;
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("End of unlimited while loop reched");
            }
        }
    };
```

For start call

```
alarmCheckThread.start();
```

For stop call

```
alarmCheckThread.interrupt();
```

Comment: `interrupt` has been deprecated and how to stop it ?