# How to create a notification every x minutes a user is continuously using his/her device

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, countdowntimer

I want to create a notification every *x* minutes a user is continuously using his/her device.

I think I'm supposed to use a background service that will listen for when the screen turns on, then I can start some sort of timer that will trigger a notification if the screen hasn't been off for *x* minutes (user entered time value).

I don't necessarily need a spoon-fed answer but some very clear direction or documentation would be extremely helpful because I have no idea what I'm doing! :)

Comment: *Also please explain from the beginning* that constitutes as 'spoon feeding'

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks, I just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to detect screen on:

Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON check out for above broadcasts registration. here https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/ you can find a good example.

when screen is on set an alarm for x time as you want 
here [How do I repeat a method every 10 minutes after a button press and end it on another button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221996/how-do-i-repeat-a-method-every-10-minutes-after-a-button-press-and-end-it-on-ano) user the accepted answer. When alarm time reaches check if the screen is still on if it is, create a notification. when the screen goes off turn of this alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that continuously using a phone means that screen is ON.

First of all, register BroadcastReceiver to keep track of ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF events. Then use Service to keep track of time that passed and create some logic to decide, when to fire a notification.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about it. Didn't know that.